# enable_if and auto return type?

Tags: c++, type-traits, enable-if

I want to use type_traits to overload by shared_ptr or not.

```
struct A {
    A(int i) : x(i) {}
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a{4};
    auto b = std::make_shared<A>(7);
    A& c = a;
    A* d = b.get();
    A* e = &a;

    std::cout << getX(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getX(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getX(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getX(d) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getX(e) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is one solution but has the problem that the return type must be pre-defined.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<!boost::has_dereference<T>::value, int> getX(T t)
{
    return t.x;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<boost::has_dereference<T>::value, int> getX(T t)
{
    return t->x;
}
```

But using the method below, I can make the return type `auto` but it kind of looks clunky.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!boost::has_dereference<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto getX(T t)
{
    return t.x;
}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<boost::has_dereference<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto getX(T t)
{
    return t->x;
}
```

Is there a method to use the first type and still get return type `auto`?

I do not want to specify the type of `A::x` and so `auto` return type would be best. The second type does that but feels a bit clunky.

Or is there a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: If you use the return type form of `std::enable_if`, you cannot use `auto` as the return type.  Perhaps `decltype(t.x)`?

Comment: Option 2 needs the least amount of maintenance.   You could use that and then when C++20 comes out switch to concepts which gets rid of the clunkyness.

Comment: You should look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552139/void-t-and-trailing-return-type-with-decltype-are-they-completely-interchangeab

Comment: `std::enable_if` is usually clunky, wherever you decide to put it. The version with the anonymous template parameter seems less clunky to me. You're left with a nice contiguous `auto getX(T t) { return .x; }` that clearly tells you the important bits of the function.

Comment: I personally would prefer tag dispatch-based solution over enable if in this scenario. Let me know if you'd like me to put together sample code.

Comment: Another approach would be a template class with static `get`, specialized for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @SergeyA I would love to see the dispatch-based solution. I've never used any of those techniques. My aim is to cut down on the clunkiness present here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to run a different line of code or two for different types then [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) lets you do that without having to use `enable_if` and allows you to use automatic return type deduction.  You can simplify `getX` into

```
template <typename T>
auto getX(T t)
{
    if constexpr (boost::has_dereference<T>::value)
        return t->x;
    else
        return t.x;
}
```

and this works because the path that is not executed is discarded so at compile time only the true path compiled.

Comment: We haven't gotten to C++17 yet in our build system :(

Comment: @Mochan Bummer.  You should add which standard you can use to the question.  Since C++17 is the current standard just using the C++ tag by itself means everything up to C++17 is okay.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution to my problem @NathanOliver. I'll keep it in the back of my mind so that when we have C++17, I will make the change.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting version using C++20 (two variants, in fact):

```
template <typename T> auto getX(T t) {
    if constexpr (requires(T t) { t->x; })
        return t->x;
    else
        return t.x;
}

template<typename T> concept HasDereference = requires(T t) { *t; };

template <typename T> auto getX_v2(T t) {
    if constexpr (HasDereference<T>)
        return t->x;
    else
        return t.x;
}

struct X {
    int x;
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << HasDereference<X> << endl;  // 0
    cout << HasDereference<X*> << endl; // 1
    X x{42};
    cout << getX(x) << endl;  // 42
    cout << getX(&x) << endl; // 42
    cout << getX_v2(x) << endl;  // 42
    cout << getX_v2(&x) << endl; // 42
}
```